# How do I link/relate two children of a Syncfusion-DockingManager?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, syncfusion, contentcontrol

I use a Syncfusion-`DockingManager` to display a `UserControl` as content of a `ContentControl`. A property `UserControl` (also as content of a `ContentControl`) can be opened which displays data related to the main user control. On closing the main content control I want to close the respective property content control too.

With `Window` objects there is the `Owner` property to set up relations. I looked for a similar property/functionality in `ContentControl` and didn't find any. It is not possible to change the parent of a `ContentControl`. I also tried to link `Children`of the `DockingManager` in syntax like `DockingManager.Children[0].IsRelatedTo(DockingManager.Children[1])`.

I could store the indices of the "children" of the main content control and close them by hand on `WindowClosing`. However there should be a be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the dependent user control as the tag of the MainUserControl. This tag can be utilized to access the dependent user control and close it when the MainUserControl is being closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed. I can also assign a list of `ContentControls` to the Tag and this way can close all linked windows at once.